# Rotate texture using vertex shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm trying to rotate a texture inside vertex shader. I have a pointer to a texture that, for my purpose, is rotated counterclockwise by 90 degrees. I **don't want** to manually rotate the texture before calling `glTexImage2D()`.

I can use `#version 120` only.

This is my original vertex shader:

```
#version 120

attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;

varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = a_position;
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
}
```

For testing purpose only, I modified the vertex shader in this way but I get a black screen:

```
#version 120

const float w = 0.76;
float mat3 A = ( 1, 0, 0,
                 0,  1, 0,
                 0,  0, 1 );

attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;

varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main()
{
    A = ( cos(w), -sin(w), 0,
          sin(w),  cos(w), 0,
               0,       0, 1 );
    gl_Position = A * vec4(a_position, 1.0f);
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
}
```

Comment: A * vec4(a_position, 1.0f);  you are multiplying a 3 X 3 matrix with vec 4.

Comment: You van create a texture matrix and multiply it with the texture coordinates  in the vertex shader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get compile errors. The assignment doesn't work:

> ```c
> A = (cos(w), -sin(w), 0,
>      sin(w),  cos(w), 0,
>      0,       0, 1 );
> ```

You have to construct a `mat3`. Then you can assign that matrix (also see [GLSL Programming/Vector and Matrix Operations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GLSL_Programming/Vector_and_Matrix_Operations)):

```c
A = mat3(cos(w), -sin(w), 0.0,
         sin(w),  cos(w), 0.0,
         0.0,     0.0,    1.0);
```

You cannot multiply a `vec4` and a `mat3`. You have to multiply the `vec3` with the `mat3`

```c
gl_Position = vec4(A * a_position, 1.0f);
```

And I even cant imagin what you expect with this line:

> ```c
> float mat3 A = ( 1, 0, 0,
>                 0,  1, 0,
>                 0,  0, 1 );
> ```

Correct would be:

```c
mat3 A = mat3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

This is the same as:

```c
mat3 A = mat3(1.0);
```

---

Correct vertex shader:

```c
#version 120

attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main()
{
    const float w = 0.76;
    mat3 A = mat3(cos(w), -sin(w), 0.0,
                  sin(w),  cos(w), 0.0,
                  0.0,     0.0,    1.0);
    gl_Position = vec4(A * a_position, 1.0);
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
}
```

Comment: @Rabbid76 very dumb error missing `mat3` in A matrix definition. Additionally, I have a very long log and I didn't see the compilation error, it was there! :D P.S.: the line `gl_Position = vec4(A * a_position, 1.0);` was correct, typing mistamtch. Thanks for your fast reply

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this code compiles in version 120 , but the general idea is to create a texture matrix.

```
layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aNormal;
layout (location = 2) in vec2 aTexCoord;



uniform mat4 textureMatrix;

out vec2 TexCoord;

void main()
{
 vec4 mTex; 
 mTex =  textureMatrix * vec4( aTexCoord.x , aTexCoord.y , 0.0 , 1.0 );
TexCoord = vec2(mTex.x , mTex.y );
}
```