# Rotate sampler2D texture using fragment shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

As per my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74487493/rotate-texture-using-vertex-shader-opengl/), what if I want to rotate a `sampler2D` texture inside the fragment shader?

In [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74487493/rotate-texture-using-vertex-shader-opengl/) question I rotated the texture inside vertex shader

```c
#version 120
    
attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
    
void main()
{
    const float w = 1.57;
    mat3 A = mat3(cos(w), -sin(w), 0.0,
                  sin(w),  cos(w), 0.0,
                  0.0,     0.0,    1.0);
    gl_Position = vec4(A * a_position, 1.0);
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
}
```

but my the fragment shader applies an heavy modification that was thought for a rotated clockwise texture, so using the vertex shader I have an horizontal effect that is applied to vertical coordinates by fragment shader.

Is it possible to *rotate* a `sampler2D` before apply the modification?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rotate a `sampler2D`, however you can rotated the texture coordinates:

```c
#version 120

attribute vec3 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;

void main()
{
    const float w = 1.57;
    mat2 uvRotate = mat2(cos(w), -sin(w),
                         sin(w),  cos(w));
    gl_Position = vec4(a_position, 1.0);
    v_texCoord = uvRotate * a_texCoord;
}
```